# Prove that the derivative of a scalar field cannot be greater than 0 for a fixed point and for every vector y

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> The definition of the derivative of a scalar field with respect to a vector was given as the following: Given a scalar field $f: S \rightarrow R$, where $S \subseteq \mathbf{R}^n$. Let $a$ be an interior point of $S$ and $y$ an arbitrary point in $\mathbf{R}^n$. Then $f'(a;y)$ is the derivative of $f$ at $a$ with respect to $y$:
>   $$
> f'(a;y) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+hy)-f(a)}{h}
> $$
>
> Prove that there is no scalar field $f'(a;y)>0$ for a fixed vector $a$ and every nonzero vector $y$.

I'm not really sure where to go with this. If $f'(a;y)>0$ for all $y$, then $f$ must be increasing in every direction around $a$, so $a$ is a minimum of $f$, maybe? I'm not even sure that's valid, so not too sure what to do, really.

Comment: Is the statement in your question correct? How about $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=x$ and $y=\pm 1$?

Comment: The definition of $f'(a;y)$ looks like a fancy word for "directional derivatives".

Answer (score 2):

If $f'(a;y)\gt0$, then $f'(a;-y)\lt0$.

If $a$ is a local minimum point of $f$, then the derivative should be zero instead of being positive for all $y$.